# Dynamic UITableViewCells height change

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I am trying to dynamically change the height but somehow its not working. The "detailText" label is overlapping the other fields of the listing. The default height of whole cell is 150, that includes, user,text,date. User and date covering one lines each and the rest with the text.
I am just about to finish the app but this is really disrupting the whole process, I have also checked other techniques, but somehow none of them is working. May be its a small thing that I am missing. :(

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *user=[[discussionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"user"];
    NSString *text=[[discussionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSString *time=[[discussionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
    CGSize usersize = [user sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGSize textsize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGSize timesize = [time sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return usersize.height+textsize.height+timesize.height;
}
```

and the connector

```
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    discussionCustomCell *cell = (discussionCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"discussionCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSLog(@"%i",[discussionArray count]);
    NSDictionary *dict=[discussionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageViewIst.image = [profileImagesArray_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *new=[dict objectForKey:@"new"];
    if ([new isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
    cell.imageViewSecond.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
    else
    {
    cell.imageViewSecond.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text=[dict objectForKey:@"user"];
    cell.nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    cell.nameLabel.numberOfLines = ceilf([[dict objectForKey:@"user"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/20.0);
    cell.detailText.text=[dict objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.detailText.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    cell.detailText.numberOfLines = ceilf([[dict objectForKey:@"text"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/20.0);
    cell.timeLabel.text=[dict objectForKey:@"date"];
    cell.timeLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    cell.timeLabel.numberOfLines = ceilf([[dict objectForKey:@"date"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(250, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/20.0);
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: do you have correct `layoutSubview` code in your `discussionCustomCell` class? If they are overlapping the bug should be there. Do you take into account those text sizes there when you calculate .frame of your nameLabel and other fields?

Comment: I know there is a bug but I am unable to get it, the sizes are checked, layout checked, there is something that I am missing.

Comment: I believe you should add `layoutSubview` code of your `discussionCustomCell` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

As demosten suggested, make sure that the labels are given correct offsets in your `discussionCustomCell`. Also please note that when you are returning height for a cell, just add up the heights of labels and the offset difference between each labels. Otherwise, there is a chance that your labels will appear outside the cell. 
ie. if user label is having height 40 and timelabel having height 40.Then the total cell height should be 80+. Hope you got the point.

Comment: Yes I have placed the correct offsets, and the height is calculated correctly. Still the problem is there, the first two are perfectly places but after that all are overlapping :(

Comment: first two means - first two rows or first two labels? Do you have a screen shot of that to share?